# I created a PowerApp that is linked to a SharePoint List. A user said 'dont allow' on the sharepoint access question, can they change to allow access?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have created a PowerApp in Microsoft PowerApps, which is linked to a SharePoint list. Most users accept the access prompt that Microsoft makes them do. However, for those that clicked 'Do not allow' accidently, there does not seem to be a way to allow them again. Is there a way?

Comment: Yes. I believe you can unshare then reshare the app with the user.

Answer (score 0):

They can open their connections page and add a sharepoint connection from there.

https://make.powerapps.com/environments/Environment_ID/connections